# How do we add JSP to provide input for jasper report in JasperServer?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I have created jrxml file and deployed it on jasper server. It provides its default input window. I want to add my own jsp to take input from user. There is option to add jsp, however I want to know how can I add jsp. I need steps.

Thanks......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I haven't done this yet, but I will be working on it later today...

In Jasperserver 4.0, make a copy of /WEB-INF/jsp/modules/inputControls/DefaultParametersForm.jsp and customize that. Then, specify the customized file in the Optional JSP location field on the Controls and Resources page.

There's more information in the JasperServer Ultimate Guide.

Comment: Have you been able to do this.  I'm trying to remove the silly "apply" button from the input control.